# JavaFX - Clicking inside GridPane prints out Pane instead of TextField

Tags: java, javafx, sudoku, gridpane

I'm trying to make a Sudoku Game in JavaFX. I made the 9x9 grid using GridPane and TextField.

Now I want to change the background color of the TextField when user clicks inside it. To check that everyting is fine I am prining the target od the MouseEvent.

My problem is that when I click in the center of TextField, the target is Pane and when i I click elsewhere the target is my GridPane and the background color is changing.

What should I do? I can't figure out how to do it!

```
public class SudokuGrid {

public static final int GRID_SIZE = 9;

private TextField[][] sudokuCells;
private GridPane sudokuGrid;

public SudokuGrid () {
    sudokuCells = new TextField[GRID_SIZE][GRID_SIZE];
    createSudokuGrid();
    for (int row = 0; row < GRID_SIZE; row++) {
        for(int col = 0; col < GRID_SIZE; col++) {
            sudokuCells[row][col] = new TextField() {
                  @Override
                    public void replaceText(int start, int end, String text) {
                        // If the replaced text would end up being invalid, then simply
                        // ignore this call!
                        if (text.matches("[1-9]|\\s")) {
                            super.setText(text);
                        }
                    }
                };
            sudokuCells[row][col].setPrefSize(60, 60);
            sudokuCells[row][col].setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow;");
            sudokuGrid.add(sudokuCells[row][col], col, row);
            sudokuGrid.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
                    Object source = e.getTarget();
                    System.out.println(source);
                    if(source instanceof TextField) {
                        ((TextField) source).setStyle("-fx-background-color: green;");
                    }
                }
                });
        }
    }   
    sudokuGrid.setPrefSize(270, 270); // 30 * 9
    sudokuGrid.setGridLinesVisible(true);
}

private void createSudokuGrid() {
    sudokuGrid = new GridPane();
    for (int i = 0; i  < GRID_SIZE; i++) {
        RowConstraints rc = new RowConstraints();
        rc.setVgrow(Priority.ALWAYS) ; // allow row to grow
        rc.setFillHeight(true); // ask nodes to fill height for row
        // other settings as needed...
        sudokuGrid.getRowConstraints().add(rc);

        ColumnConstraints cc = new ColumnConstraints();
        cc.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS) ; // allow column to grow
        cc.setFillWidth(true); // ask nodes to fill space for column
        // other settings as needed...
        sudokuGrid.getColumnConstraints().add(cc);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `source` of the event is the object on which you set the event filter; i.e. in this case it is `sudokuGrid`. So the condition

```
if (source instanceof TextField)
```

in your handler will never be true, since the only possible source is the `sudokuGrid`.

If you want to change the background color of the text field, you can add the event filter to the text field itself:

```
TextField sudokuCell = sudokuCells[row][col];
sudokuCell.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, e -> 
    sudokuCell.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green;"));
```

Better still would be to respond to changes in the text field's focused property (because using a mouse listener will not change the background if the user uses the Tab key to navigate to different text fields):

```
TextField sudokuCell = sudokuCells[row][col];
sudokuCell.focusedProperty().addListener((obs, wasFocused, isNowFocused) -> {
    if (isNowFocused) {
        sudokuCell.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green;");
    } else {
        sudokuCell.setStyle("");
    }
});
```

And even better would just be to use an external css file to do this:

sudoku-grid.css:

```css
.text-field:focused {
    -fx-background-color: green ;
}
```

and then in your Java code associate the CSS file with the grid:

```
sudokuGrid.getStyleSheets().add("sudoku-grid.css");
```

and remove the handlers entirely.

Comment: Thank you. I used the last option. It seems to be the easisest. but I had to add this code `sudokuCells[row][col].getStyleClass().add("text-field");` to make it work.

Comment: @ValentinEmilCudelcu It should work without that. A `TextField` has a style class of `text-field` [by default](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#textfield). (Btw mark the answer as correct if it answers the question.)

Comment: No idea, why it doesn't work without it, but thanks for help.